# update and display in gridview (ASP c#)

Tags: c#, sql

can someone tell me where is the error in this code :

```
 protected void btnValiderModifier_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                string myid;
                for (int i = 0; i < gv_enfant.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    CheckBox chbox = (CheckBox)gv_enfant.Rows[i].Cells[0].FindControl("CheckBoxenfant");
                    if (chbox.Checked)
                    {
                        myid = ((HiddenField)gv_enfant.Rows[i].Cells[0].FindControl("codeenfant")).Value;

                }
            }

            c.cmd = c.cn.CreateCommand();
            c.cmd.CommandText = "update Enfants set prenom ='" + TextBox_NPmodif.Text + "',DateNaissance='" + TextBox_DNmodif.Text + "', Scolarise='" + TextBox_Scolarisemodif.Text + "',Activite= '" + TextBox_Activitemodif.Text +"' where codeEnfants =" + myid;
            if (c.cn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                c.cn.Open();
            }
            c.cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            Response.Write("<script>alert('Opération reussie')</script>");
            gv_enfant.DataBind();

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write("<script>alert ('Erreur lors de la modif!')</script>");
        }
        finally
        {
            if (c.cn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                c.cn.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

this code make an update in table "Enfants" then it display iu gridview , when i debug i have this error = "  Incorrect syntax near '='  "
**thank you**

Comment: Which line throws the error?

Comment: When you get the error, what is the actual SQL query being executed?  Note also that your code is ***wide open*** to SQL injection.  It's even very likely that the syntax error is a result of that vulnerability.  You should *at least* use parameterized queries.  Additionally, your error handling is *explicitly ignoring* exceptions.  Exceptions tend to contain meaningful information about the error they encountered, you should at least be logging that information.

Comment: in `catch(Exception ex)`

Answer (score 0):

My reputation isn't high enough to add a comment, but I have to ask: is "myid" definitely an integer/double? If not, you'll have to enclose it in single quotes as well.

Answer (score 0):

You decalre myid as a string then you forgot to quote it `where codeEnfants =" + myid;`

You should not add the parameters this way anyway, try like this:

```
protected void btnValiderModifier_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
    {
            string myid;
            for (int i = 0; i < gv_enfant.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                CheckBox chbox = (CheckBox)gv_enfant.Rows[i].Cells[0].FindControl("CheckBoxenfant");
                if (chbox.Checked)
                {
                    myid = ((HiddenField)gv_enfant.Rows[i].Cells[0].FindControl("codeenfant")).Value;

                }
            }
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("update Enfants set prenom =@prenom,  DateNaissance=@dateNaissance, Scolarise=@scolarise, Activite=@activite where codeEnfants=@codeEnfants", conn);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prenom", TextBox_NPmodif.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateNaissance", TextBox_DNmodif.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Scolarise", TextBox_Scolarisemodif.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Activite", TextBox_Activitemodif.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@codeEnfants", myid);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            //success!
            Response.Write("<script>alert('Opération reussie')</script>");
            gv_enfant.DataBind();
        }
        catch(SqlException sqlEx)
        {
            //fail!
            //what is the point of cacthing if you do use the exception?
            Response.Write("error" + sqlEx.Message);
            Response.Write("<script>alert ('Erreur lors de la modif!')</script>");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Meryem I was trying to extract the method in a seperated function, see my edit, and post the error dont just say it does not work

Comment: i can't put this string not assigned.
 error in this line :                 `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@codeEnfants", myid);`

Comment: What? sorry I could not understand

Comment: you wrote `string myid;` it's mot assigned , i think it should like `string myid ="";` but it's not working

Comment: @Meryem oh ok I understand, after the for loop make sure you have an Id for code enfant, display it `Response.Write("myid = " + myid);`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46176/discussion-between-meda-and-meryem)